# dealing with pointers in realloc?

Tags: c, realloc

Please look at the following code

```
char *line = (char *) malloc(100);
char *newline,*source = line;
int size=100;
newline = realloc ( line , size +=size);
// assuming that newline has been successfully assigned the demanded memory and line is           freed
```

Now my question here is that can i write in future expression like

```
source = newline +( line - source );
```

I am having doubt in mind because i am using the `line` pointer which is freed after the successful operation of the `realloc()` but My program ( this only a snippet from it ) is

still working?so is it safe to use `line` pointer after `realloc()` has done?

Comment: Error: it should be `char *newline, *source = line;`

Comment: `newline + ( line + 10 )` won't compile, it's trying to add two pointers together.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe to use the line pointer after realloc is done. realloc changes the size of the block pointed to by line. If the size increases, the old location may not have enough contiguous space to accommodate the new larger block. So the location of the block in the memory changes. Use the pointer returned by realloc.
If the old location does not have enough contiguous space for the larger block requested by the user, realloc tries to find a new block of the required size (like malloc), copies the elements from the old block and frees the old block.
If realloc fails, the old pointer is valid and must be freed. If realloc succeeds, the old pointer is considered invalid and should not be freed.
Also, the fact that your program is working is not always a good way to check if something is correct. For example, if you declare `int a[10]` and you access `a[10]` or `a[11]` it may not fail most of the time but it's still undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> so is it safe to use 'linepointer afterrealloc()` has done?

No, because realloc() may free your input buffer while making the new one(if new one is larger than the previous size). And realloc would copy the previous user data from the old buffer into new buffer. So user should use the new buffer as it contains all older information not the old one.

This is about realloc()

> void *realloc(void *p, size_t size) realloc changes the size of the
>   object pointed to by p to size. The contents will be unchanged up to
>   the minimum of the old and new sizes. If the new size is larger, the
>   new space is uninitialized. realloc returns a pointer to the new
>   space, or NULL if the request cannot be satisfied, in which case *p is
>   unchanged.